Wightman correlation, local Lorentzian correlations
They say local Lorentzian correlations are not real functions, but a tempered distribution for Schwarz functions. That is, they are only defined with some smearing. But I always see this only in the context of taking Euclidean correlation and wick rotating to Local Lorentzian correlations. Are local Lorentzian correlations always a distribution, i.e. Wightman functions? What does that mean for quantum computing or something where people calculate local Lorentzian correlations all the time. Do you also need to keep time ordering for Euclidean time even in such case to regulate the high energy states?
